# Table contains multiple rows each row has textview and button share, how to identify each row components?

Tags: android

I'm creating android application that get texts from db ,and show them as a table
where number of rows depend on number of texts on that db
each text will be shown on row and a share button beside it

I created 2 layouts , 1 for my table and another for each row
now I fill each row with a function addtablerow 
but how can I identify each button for exact row ?

cause only last button works well and other button has no action??
I thought of creating array of buttons but always it crashes on creation !

for more details here is my code

activity_main.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" >
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_table"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    android:shrinkColumns="1"/>
</ScrollView>
```

table_row_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:clickable="true"
android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cell"

/>
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="7dp"
    android:layout_height="77dp"
    android:text="Button" />
</TableRow>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.tabletest.test;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public int i;
public Button btn;
public TextView tv;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    i=1; //just for test , but later i will get position of data on db
    addTableRow();
    i=2;
    addTableRow();

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int j=btn.getId();
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(
                    android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            String shareBody = "this is"+j;
            sharingIntent
                    .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,     shareBody);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via: "));
        }

    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
private void addTableRow() {
    final TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_table);
    final TableRow tr = (TableRow) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.table_row_item, null);

    // fill cell txt
    tv = (TextView) tr.findViewById(R.id.cell);
    tv.setText("This is row"+i);
    table.addView(tr);

    btn=(Button) tr.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setId(i);


    registerForContextMenu(tr);
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think by the sound of it, you probably want to be using a [listview](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) intead of a tablelayout, but that's not really the problem.

The major issue is that btn and tv should not be global members of the activity.  The reason the last button works is because you are re-initializing your button, btn, to be equal to a new button.  Thus, the last one is the only one that actually works.  My suggestion is that you make these local instance variables like this:

```
private void addTableRow() {
final TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_table);
final TableRow tr = (TableRow) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.table_row_item, null);

// fill cell txt
TextView tv = (TextView) tr.findViewById(R.id.cell);
tv.setText("This is row"+i);
table.addView(tr);

Button btn=(Button) tr.findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setId(i);


registerForContextMenu(tr);
```

}

Then, to keep track of what is in each row, I would create a class to hold your data.  Here is an example:

```
public class myRow{
    String text;
    int id;
    //any other data you want to track
}
```

Then, in your activity, create an arraylist(from your db) of these objects.  When someone clicks on an item of the array list, you simply retrieve that element of the list, and do an action based upon that.

If you still need more assitance on a listview, or this didn't work let me know and I will help!